# How to get old value and new value and compare them

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a piece of code, but am unsure if it's correct.

I want to read the balance from my account and do something if the value is higher than it was before.

Here is what I did until now:

```
var prof = document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG')[0].childNodes[0].data / 500;  // balance field

if (document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG')[0].childNodes[0].data >= 0) // if balance is higher than 0
    document.getElementsByClassName('Link-q08rh0-0 fODGkp')[0].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('NavLink__StylesNavLink-sc-140hi5a-0 etHlta')[3].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('Button__StyledButton-sc-8bd3dp-0 fGwihv')[0].click(); // click trezor
    document.getElementsByClassName('styles__InputField-ix7z99-3 gQVvYS')[0].value= prof; // enter the amount
    document.getElementsByClassName('Button__StyledButton-sc-8bd3dp-0 fbjzSA')[0].click(); // click button
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't seem to be formatted well. Can you format that? And please mention the issue / error you might be facing while running the code. Thanks.

Comment: I totally agree with @Vasanth. Also, if you want to execute multiple lines of code after an `if` statement, you have to use the curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

1. As I understand, You are using the CSS module in your project and your code depended on runtime generated CSS names and the problem is every time you build or run the project all CSS names will generate again by new suffixes. And this code will not works.
   For namely, this CSS class `styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG` will be changed to something else like `styles__Content-rsg876o-1 sd07gs` into your next build. So, the solution is using a unique `id` for every element which you need.
2. You should store the previous balance in every check and compare it with that value.

   ```js
   var prevValue = 0;
   var prof = document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG')[0].childNodes[0].data / 500;  
   //ballance field
   var balance = document.getElementsByClassName('styles__Content-rlm06o-1 ixoRjG')[0].childNodes[0].data;
   if (balance >= prevValue) {  //if ballance is higher than 0
     document.getElementsByClassName('Link-q08rh0-0 fODGkp')[0].click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('NavLink__StylesNavLink-sc-140hi5a-0 etHlta')[3].click();
     document.getElementsByClassName('Button__StyledButton-sc-8bd3dp-0 fGwihv')[0].click();
     
     oldValue = balance;
   }
   ```

Comment: to 1) no thats not the pboblem.

Comment: the problem is you in 2) mentiond thing.

Comment: var prevValue = 0;

  
  oldValue = balance;